# Devise with Rails 4: user show route doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using the devise gem to handle all the sign up and sign in stuff. But I also want to add user profiles to my application, so I generated a user controller with only a show action. Then I added `get 'users/:id' => 'users#show'` to routes.rb. In fact, typing /users/1 works, but I can't find a way to name the route. **What I want** is to get something like show_user_path or user_path so I can link to a given user's content and show that user's profile.

Here is my routes.rb

```
Pinteresting::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :pins
  get 'users/:id' => 'users#show'
  devise_for :users 

  root "pins#index"
  get "about" => "pages#about"
```

And here are the routes I get with it (I highlighted the one I expect to be something like show_user_path):

```
pins_path                        GET     /pins(.:format)     pins#index
                                 POST    /pins(.:format)     pins#create
new_pin_path                     GET     /pins/new(.:format)     pins#new
edit_pin_path                    GET     /pins/:id/edit(.:format)    pins#edit
pin_path                         GET     /pins/:id(.:format)     pins#show
                                 PATCH   /pins/:id(.:format)     pins#update
                                 PUT     /pins/:id(.:format)     pins#update
                                 DELETE  /pins/:id(.:format)     pins#destroy
#this is the one I want a path!  GET     /users/:id(.:format)    users#show
new_user_session_path        GET     /users/sign_in(.:format)    devise/sessions#new
user_session_path                        POST    /users/sign_in(.:format)    devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session_path        DELETE  /users/sign_out(.:format)   devise/sessions#destroy
user_password_path               POST    /users/password(.:format)   devise/passwords#create
new_user_password_path       GET     /users/password/new(.:format)       devise/passwords#new
edit_user_password_path      GET     /users/password/edit(.:format)      devise/passwords#edit
                                 PATCH   /users/password(.:format)   devise/passwords#update
                                 PUT     /users/password(.:format)   devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration_path    GET     /users/cancel(.:format)     devise/registrations#cancel
user_registration_path       POST    /users(.:format)    devise/registrations#create
new_user_registration_path       GET     /users/sign_up(.:format)    devise/registrations#new
edit_user_registration_path      GET     /users/edit(.:format)   devise/registrations#edit
                                 PATCH   /users(.:format)    devise/registrations#update
                                 PUT     /users(.:format)    devise/registrations#update
                                 DELETE  /users(.:format)    devise/registrations#destroy
root_path                        GET     /   pins#index
about_path                       GET     /about(.:format)    pages#about
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For devise, `User` is not the resource, it's just a scope. What devise cares about is authentication.

Although the paths are nested under `/user`, you will notice that the resources that are defined are actually things like sessions, registrations, passwords...

Just add `resources :users` in your routes and create a `UsersController` (and the views).

If you don't want to create all the resources for users and just be able to user `user_path(user)` with your `get 'users/:id`, you can name that route using the `as` option, like this:

```
get 'users/:id' => 'users#show', as: user
```

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is great but I think it's worth noting here that if you don't want to create a different controller, but want to add an action to, say, your registrations controller that you inherit from the Devise::RegistrationsController, then you need to use the [devise scope block](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper#devise_scope-instance_method):

```
devise_scope :user do
  get 'users/:id' => 'registrations#show', as: user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer supposed to be like this:

```
get 'user/:id' => 'users#show', as: :user
```

Comment: How is it different from the accepted answer above?